# How to replace every digit after special character '$' with '*'

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a file which contain data like below

Data in file :

```
axbnx $56 ghjas $78$
axbnx $5** ghjas $ 
axbnx $006 ghjas $$678
```

Needed Output in below form :

```
axbnx $** ghjas $**$
axbnx $*** ghjas $ 
axbnx $*** ghjas $$***
```

My code : [*It is not working*]

```
sed -E 's/$[[:digit:]]/*/g'
```

Try to work on this emulator : https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler

Comment: Remarkably similar, within less than day of the other one. Is this an assignment somewhere?

Comment: with your last edit, you completely attempting to change the question completely, so I rollback it

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`

```bsh
$ perl -pe 's/\$\K\d+/$&=~s|.|*|gr/ge' ip.txt
axbnx $** ghjas $**$
axbnx $*** ghjas $ 
axbnx $*** ghjas $$***
```

- `\$\K\d+` match digits preceded by `$` character (`\K` will prevent `$` from being part of matched portion in `$&`)
- `$&=~s|.|*|gr` replace each character of matched portion with `*`
- `e` flag to allow use of Perl code in replacement section

You can also use `perl -pe 's/\$\d+/$&=~tr|0-9|*|r/ge'`

Answer (score 2):

with adjusting a small change [on my answer to your previously asked question](/a/619782/72456), changing `[^*]` (non-star character) to `[0-9]` digit, you could do:

```
sed -E ':a s/(\$\**)[0-9]/\1*/; ta' infile
```

---

I'm not sure that if you want to preserve patterns like `$***123` from being converted or not as pointed in comment too, but to prevent that, you can change first character after `$` for these patterns to something like `$<Uniq-character-or-string>*` then do change on rest of the patterns and revert that pattern back to previous state with:

```
sed -E ':a s/\$\*/$Uniq*/;ta;
        :b s/(\$\**)[0-9]/\1*/; tb;
        :c s/\$Uniq\*/$*/; tc;
' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk '{while ( match($0,/(.*)(\$[0-9]+)(.*)/,a) ) $0=a[1] gensub(/[0-9]/,"*","g",a[2]) a[3]} 1' file
axbnx $** ghjas $**$
axbnx $*** ghjas $
axbnx $*** ghjas $$***
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` program will successively replace the digits in the pattern "`$` followed by one or more digits" by the `*`:

```
awk '{do {$0=gensub(/(\$\**)[[:digit:]]/,"\\1*","g");} while ($0~/\$\**[[:digit:]]/)}1' input.txt
```

It does so by replacing the pattern "`$` followed by zero or more `*` and then one digit" with "everything before the digit, and then one `*`" (the `gensub()` call), and looping until no occurences of the search pattern remain.

The syntax in the `gensub()` call instructs `awk` to search for the pattern `$`, zero or more `*`, and one digit, and store everything before the digit (which is enclose in parentheses) into a "capture group". In the replacement text for this pattern, this "capture group" is referenced by the `\\1` and copied as-is, but the digit is omitted and a literal `*` substituted instead.